# onChangeListener on numberPicker

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, android-softkeyboard, picker

is it possible to have an onChangeListener for an numberPicker only when a number was entered by the softkeyboard?
The Listener should not be executed when the number is changed gy +/-. Only when the user entered a number from the softkeyboard.

The goal is that the the next pickeritem should get the focus after a user entered a number in the previous item.
So the user gets ready to enter a number like "12345" and each pickeritem gets its own value:

```
Picker0=1
Picker1=2
Picker3=3
Picker4=4
Picker5=5
```

Ist that possible or is that the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I dislike focus that moves on its own when I could have made a mistake - for instance if I pressed 4 instead of 5 and it takes me to the next picker, I would be irritated.  You might consider changing focus when the user hits the enter key... either way though, you'll want to set up an onKeyUp event in your activity or dialog, looking for the keycodes that represent a change in focus (be that enter key or number)

```
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
    //blah
    return true;
  }
  else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1) // sadly you'll have to put in a
    //blah                                // comparison for each number here
    return false; // Return false b/c you want the picker to receive number input
  }
  return false;
}
```